# Глобальная функция в angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Как следующий кусок кода сделать глобальной функцией и вызывать из многих контроллеров?

```
ref.onAuth(function (authData) {
    if (authData) {
        console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
        $scope.authExist = true;
    } else {
        console.log("User is logged out");
        $scope.authExist = false;
    }
    return $scope.authExist;
});
```

Comment: а зачем ее делать глобальной? вариантов куча: начиная с объявления ее в скопе верхнего уровня. до избавления от использования внутри `scope` и переноса функции в сервис. Какой вариант лучше сказать нельзя, так как  неизвестно что, как и где используется

Comment: этот пример помог -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541179/global-functions-in-angularjs

Comment: Не стоит все пихать в `$rootScope`, кроме того, всегда есть несколько вариантов решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через [Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

Попробуй так

```
angular.module('App', []).
controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'ref', function ($scope, ref) {
    ref.onAuth({uid:1,provider:'someProvider'});
}]).
factory('ref', [function($scope) {
    function onAuth (authData) {
        var authExist = false;
        if (authData) {
            console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
            authExist = true;
        } else {
            console.log("User is logged out");
        }
        return authExist;
    }
    return {
        onAuth:onAuth
    };
}]);
```

Регистрируешь его как `service`,а потом пользуешься в контроллерах принадлежащих этому модулю.

Comment: в сервис нельзя добавить в зависимости `$scope`, то есть код, приведенный в ответе - не работает и выдает ошибку: _Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- ref_

Comment: да я знаю что $scope не работает , Ty

Comment: Esli ego pribindid то почему не работает,хорошо тоже работает,я добавил его в ответ.
factory('ref', ['$scope',function($scope) { ...

Comment: нет, отредактированный вариант ничем не отличается - это по прежнему **не работает**

Comment: Да точно $scope нельзя переедать в сервисе,Я обновил ответ.Srvice eто же такой провайдер получаеться как и $scope.можно в нем обработать данные а потом возвратить.а потом в контроллере присвоить уже